# ASP MVC Nested Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models

I need a view that displays rows of header-detail info.  For a trivial case I set up a Course-Student tiny database with 4 simple tables.  The Courses and Students tables are linked with a Section table which also has a student grade in it.  Also, the Student table is owned by a Student Type Table.  There are helper classes to hold the list of "header" data for the course and a "detail" list for each student who takes that class.

```
namespace SchoolA.Models
{
public class CourseInfo2
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CourseSectionList> CourseStudentList { get; set; }
}
}
namespace SchoolA.Models
{
public class CourseSectionList
{
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
}
```

The controller is:

```
public ActionResult Courselisting()
    {
        List<CourseInfo2> courseInfo2 = new List<CourseInfo2>();
        List<CourseSectionList> courseSectionList = new List<CourseSectionList>();
        var Cquery = from c in db.Courses select c;
        foreach (var item in Cquery)
        {
            Course course = db.Courses.Find(item.CourseID);   // first find the selected course
            // get the sections
                        foreach (var s in query)  // go through each section
                        {
                           // get the section data
                            courseSectionList.Add(new CourseSectionList
                            {
                                Student = student.StudentName,
                                Type = studentType.StudentTypeName,
                                Grade = s.SectionStudentGrade        
                            });
                        }  // end of section loop
            courseInfo2.Add(new CourseInfo2
            {
                CourseID = course.CourseID,
                CourseNumber = course.CourseNumber,
                CourseName = course.CourseName,
                CourseStudentList = courseSectionList
            });
        }   // end of Course loop
        return View(courseInfo2);    // Course List and Section list for each course
    }
```

The View is:

```
    @model SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2                            
@*  doesn't work either: model List<SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2>*@
<div>
     <table>
        <tr><th>ID</th> <th>Number</th> <th>Course</th></tr>
        @foreach (var CourseInfo2 in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @CourseInfo2.CourseID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @CourseInfo2.CourseNumber
                </td>
                <td>
                    @CourseInfo2.CourseName

                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr><th>Student</th> <th>Type</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
                        @foreach (var s in Model.CourseStudentList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @s.Student
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @s.Type
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @s.Grade
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that I get a variety of errors as I try to pass these two models to the view.  In the code as shown above I get this error:

```
CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of  type 'SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2' because 'SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

I've tried a number of variations for passing the models but always run into one error other the other that prevents both models from working in the view.  I should note that I tested each part of the view independently and the controller code works fine to deliver the correct data to the view.  However, I can't combine the two.

The problem seems to be the way I create instances of the models an how they are passed to the view.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing your view a `List<SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2>`, but the view expects a single `SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2`.

Change your @model declaration to `IEnumerable<SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2>`.

Then change your `foreach` loops.

Change the first loop to `foreach (var courseInfo in Model)`

Change the inner loop to `foreach (var s in courseInfo.CourseStudentList)`

Comment: JB06 - OMG! That worked and I realize my mistake now.  I fiddled with this a long time - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a model which is **list of object**, while in view you have **single object**.

Change your view model bind as below:

```
@model List<SchoolA.Models.CourseInfo2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I have to edit  Level2Name  (by UI it's a textbox inside the child grid).

I'm able to edit `Level1name` (parent grid text field) and able to get value in my controller.

Question: How do I able to edit the nested `textbox`.

What I've tried.

Code:

**Model**

```
public class Level0
        {
            public Level0()
            {
                Level1= new List<Level1>();                
            }
            public int? ID{ get; set; }
            public int? NameText{ get; set; }           
            public List<Level1> lev1{ get; set; }
        }

        public class Level1
        {
            public Level1()
            {
                Level2= new List<Level2>();
            }
            public int  Lev1ID  {get;set;}
            public string Level1name{ get; set; }
            public List<Level2> level2{ get; set; }
        }    
        public class Level2
        {
            public string Level2_ID { get; set; }
            public string Level2Name{ get; set; }
        }
```

**UI Code**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Level1.Count; i++)
   {    
     @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Floors[i].Lev1ID  ) 

     @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Level1[i].Level2.Count; j++)
        {
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Level1[i].Level2[j].OP)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Level1[i].Level2[j].Level2Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        }
    }
```